# Hide subtotals for one of the values in Pivot Table

Tags: excel, excel-2007, pivot-table

The issue is in a Pivot Table on Excel 2007. In my column I have a Year field, and my values are sum of Amount, and Max of Date. The Max of Date value doesn't need any subtotals of grand totals. Is there a way to omit totals on on of the value fields, and not the other?

Eg:

```
        2013             2014
        Date    Amt      Date    Amt   Grand Totals
                                                Amt
Comp1   1/1/01  12       1/2/01  10             22 
Comp2   1/3/02  15       1/3/02  5              20
Totals          27               15
```

Comment: I don't think that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

A hack: Hide the Date Total column and format the Date Grand Totals by row with the same colour font as their highlighting.